# How to fetch dynamically qr code text vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, qr-code

I can create Qr code from document.

```
<qr-code text=""></qr-code>
```

When I read qr code from my phone Its shows text value on the screen. I want to set my API datas on text.

According to document we can use v-bind propertiy but when I use doesnt see anything on the screen.

```
<input type="text" v-model="message">

<qr-code :text="message"></qr-code>
```

How can I create dynamically qr code? How can I set API datas on text propertiy?